# How to get my specific Item index on inventory when pickup items?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to make some inventory system for my game, and I found some issue when collecting the item, what I want here matching the index `Inventory_UI system` exactly the same as `currentIndex` on the collected item, then display it on `Inventory_UI system`, let say I pickUp some item with the `currentIndex = 1` so on `Inventory_UI system` `index=1` too and so on. this happening when inventory description too so the `id` is same as `itemIndex` picked up.

### so here the the script:

- ItemManager( this for information of item ):

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class theItems
{
    public string Name;
    public GameObject[] allCurrentPrefabs;
    public int numberOfIndex;
    public AudioClip[] allSound;
    public string[] terjemahannya;
    public string[] latinnya;
}

public class _ItemManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static _ItemManager instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public List<theItems> items;

    [Header("SurahApa")]
    public int Surah;

    [Header("SoundStuff")]
    public AudioSource aSource;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void PlaySurah(int surahnya, int ayatnya)
    {
        aSource.clip = items[surahnya].allSurahSound[ayatnya];
        aSource.Play();
    }
}
```

- CollectibleItem ( this attach to each item )

```cs
 public static _CollectibleAyat instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public enum InteractionType
    {
        none, pickUp, Examine
    }

    public InteractionType interactType;

    public int currentIndex;

    public string terjemahannya;
    public string latinnya;
    public GameObject allCurrentPrefabs;

    public UnityEvent customevent;

    public void Reset()
    {
        GetComponent<Collider2D>().isTrigger = true;
    }

    public void interact()
    {
        switch (interactType)
        {
            //case InteractionType.none:
            //    Debug.Log("None");
            //    break;
            case InteractionType.Examine:

                _InteractSystem.instance.Examine(this);

                Debug.Log("Examine");

                break;
            case InteractionType.pickUp:
                // Add the object to the pickUpItems List
                // Delete the Object

                _InventorySystem.instance.PickUpItem(gameObject);
                gameObject.SetActive(false);

                Debug.Log("PickingUp");
                break;
            default:

                Debug.Log("Null Item");
                break;
        }

        //Invoke (Call) the custom Event(s)
        customevent.Invoke();
    }
```

- This InventorySystem( when item pickup)

```cs
public static _InventorySystem instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    [Header("GeneralFields")]
    public List<GameObject> items = new List<GameObject>();
    public bool isOpen;
    public int ayah;

    [Header("UI Items Section")]
    public GameObject UI_InventoryWindow;
    public Image[] item_Images;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            ToggleInventory();
        }
    }

    public void ToggleInventory()
    {
        isOpen = !isOpen;
        UI_InventoryWindow.SetActive(isOpen);
    }

    public void PickUpItem(GameObject item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
        Update_UI();
    }

    public void Update_UI()
    {
        HideAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            item_Images[i].sprite = items[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
            item_Images[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        }

    }

    public void HideAll()
    {
        foreach (var i in item_Images)
        {
            i.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    //SampeSini
    public void ShowDescription(int id)
    {


    }

    public void HideDescription()
    {

    }
```

- InteractSystem ( this is for interact and storing collectibleItem system)

```cs
 public static _InteractSystem instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public Transform detectionPoint;

    public const float detectionRadius = .2f;

    public LayerMask detectionLayer;

    public GameObject detectedObject;

    public GameObject examinePanel;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (DetectedObject())
        {
            if (PickUpInput())
            {
                detectedObject.GetComponent<_CollectibleAyat>().interactType = _CollectibleAyat.InteractionType.pickUp;
                detectedObject.GetComponent<_CollectibleAyat>().interact();
                _UIManager.instance.BackToGameFromExamine();
            }

            if (ExamineInput())
            {
                detectedObject.GetComponent<_CollectibleAyat>().interactType = _CollectibleAyat.InteractionType.Examine;
                detectedObject.GetComponent<_CollectibleAyat>().interact();
            }
        }
    }

    bool PickUpInput()
    {
        return CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1");
    }

    bool ExamineInput()
    {
        return CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire2");
    }

    bool DetectedObject()
    {
        Collider2D obj = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(detectionPoint.position, detectionRadius, detectionLayer);
        if (obj == null)
        {
            detectedObject = null;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            detectedObject = obj.gameObject;
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(detectionPoint.position, detectionRadius);
    }

    public void Examine(_CollectibleAyat items)
    {
        examinePanel.SetActive(true);

        items.terjemahannya = _QuranManager.instance.quran[_QuranManager.instance.Surah].terjemahannya[items.currentAyah].ToString();
        items.latinnya = _QuranManager.instance.quran[_QuranManager.instance.Surah].latinnya[items.currentAyah].ToString();
        items.allCurrentSurahPrefabs = _QuranManager.instance.quran[_QuranManager.instance.Surah].allCurrentSurahPrefabs[items.currentAyah];

        var go = Instantiate(items.allCurrentSurahPrefabs, _UIManager.instance.instantiatePosition.position,Quaternion.identity);
        go.transform.SetParent(_UIManager.instance.instantiatePosition.transform);

        _UIManager.instance.terjemahanText.text = items.terjemahannya;
        _UIManager.instance.latinText.text = items.latinnya;
    }
```

### Here is the Preview :

1. 

[image]

2.
[image]

note: on the `ShowDescription(int id)` i want to show item information that same as I picked up I have mentioned at first above.

Comment: If as you say the `_CollectibleAyat` is attached to multiple objects in your scene than `public static _CollectibleAyat instance;` makes no sense at all ;) Instead of storing the picked up `GameObject` you should probably rather pass on and store the picked up `theItems` instances

Comment: @derHugo okay, that makes me confuse so I have to directly store `the items` class than `CollectibleAyat`, Sorry if you don't mind could you explain in more detail? I don't understand.

Comment: Currently you are nowhere storing the `_CollectibleAyat` either .. you store `GameObject` ... you later want to be able compare the `theItem` (at least that's what your question states) so you would probably want to rather store `public List<theItems> items = new List<theItems>();` and compare these

Comment: sorry I didn't mention it where the `_collectibeAyat` I've updated the question, so basically its called when examine btn press  @derHugo